# Active target for Xcode syntax highlighting

Tags: ios, xcode, syntax-highlighting, xcode15

In my project, I have several binary targets and a few files which are included in multiple binaries.

Consider a file containing, eg.:

```swift
        #if TARGET_APP
        eventParameters["app_container"] = "app" // dimmed in the editor
        #elseif TARGET_AUTOFILL
        eventParameters["app_container"] = "autofill" // not dimmed
        #endif
```

Which is a member of both the `App` and the `App-AutoFill` binary targets.

[image: Target Membership for the file includes both the App and App-AutoFill targets]

The targets have build settings where `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` is set to either `TARGET_APP` or `TARGET_AUTOFILL` respectively.
This allows me to bundle slightly different run-time code in the app vs. the auto-fill extension binary.

What eludes me is how I can make Xcode index/highlight the above accurately. Of course, it will depend on which target the editor is highlighting for. It seems that my Xcode is highlighting for the `App-AutoFill` target, not the `App` target, causing the first condition to gray out and the second to be evaluated for syntax and indexing.

**How do I tell Xcode to switch highlighting to use a different target?**
I would prefer my `App` target to be the principal for syntax highlighting as that one contains the bulk of my code, or ideally even be able to choose the active one. This is especially cumbersome for grayed out code that defines types used frequently by the app.

My selected scheme builds the `App` target which embeds the `App-AutoFill` product using an `Embed Foundation Extensions` build phase.
[image: App binary target with App-AutoFill dependency in the scheme selector]

Comment: It's based on the currently selected build target and destination.

Comment: Also see Xcode -> Settings -> Text Editing -> Display -> Dim inactive code.

Comment: I see you added a bounty. What answer are you looking for beyond "select the desired target"?

Comment: @HangarRash you'll find from the description that simply selecting a scheme with the desired target is inadequate. The scheme selected in this case is `Spectre` whose executable is provided by the `Spectre` target which has `TARGET_APP` defined, and yet this code is dimmed in the editor.
This may be due to the fact that there is a dependency from the `Spectre` target on the `Spectre-AutoFill` target, but it is unclear how this works or how in such a situation one can enable the `TARGET_APP` codepath in the editor.